# Symfony2 - Generate input fields based on entity

Tags: arrays, forms, dynamic, formbuilder, symfony-2.8

I'm having a trouble with creating a dynamic form in Symfony2.

What i wanna do is to register a collection of text field which are generated from an entity.

I dont know where to start exactly but here's a kinda of pseudo-code of what im trying to do :

in my view :

```
   {# list_type_url are retrieved from DB #}
   {% for url in list_type_url %}
       <input type="text" name="link[{{ url.name }}]">
   {% endfor %}
```

I started in my form builder with this :

```
  $builder->add('link', CollectionType::class)
```

but I dont know how to link the array in the view with the form.

Maybe Im thinking it wrong ?

**EDIT:**

I edit the post to make things clearer  : 
the list_type_url variable is coming from an another entity. Let's says it is named UrlType, in which I can create a type of url.

Then in an another entity, imagine "Contact", i want to be able to add all the type of existing url.

so concretely, I could create 3 types of url or more (lets say top, middle, bottom) and in my contact form, i have to display those 3 types and fill them with different urls and i should be able to retrieve each of the types for a particular contact.

I've also readed [how to dynamically modify forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-user-data) but I really don't see how to use it with my problem

I hope i get more clearier

Comment: Have you read [the collection documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage) already?

Comment: yes I have read this but unless i didnt understand to do it, I still dont know how to link field with the generated input